# haskell return [] for data from a parser function

Tags: haskell, null

In the code below, I am supposed to get [] after running parse noun:

```
parse noun       "something"      = []
```

Unfortunately I can not change the signature of the function so Maybe is not an option.
How can I return [] from the noun function when running
*parse noun "something"*
?? (I don't want to return the 'c' variable)
Many thanks for your help.

```
import Parsing
    
data Tree = Branch Sort [Tree]
          | Leaf Sort String deriving (Eq, Show)
nouns :: [String]
nouns = ["flight", "breeze", "trip", "morning"]


oneOf :: [String] -> Parser String
oneOf l = do
  cs <- token identifier
  guard (elem cs l)
  return cs

noun :: Parser Tree
noun = do
   cs <- token identifier
   let a = Leaf Noun cs
   let b = parse (oneOf nouns) cs
   let c = Leaf Noun []
   if null b then return c else return a
```

---

```
-- Parsing.hs

-- Functional parsing library from chapter 13 of Programming in Haskell,
-- Graham Hutton, Cambridge University Press, 2016.

module Parsing (module Parsing, module Control.Applicative) where

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char

-- Basic definitions

newtype Parser a = P (String -> [(a,String)])

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
parse (P p) inp = p inp

item :: Parser Char
item = P (\inp -> case inp of
                     []     -> []
                     (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)])

-- Sequencing parsers

instance Functor Parser where
   -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
   fmap g p = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                            []        -> []
                            [(v,out)] -> [(g v, out)])

instance Applicative Parser where
   -- pure :: a -> Parser a
   pure v = P (\inp -> [(v,inp)])

   -- <*> :: Parser (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
   pg <*> px = P (\inp -> case parse pg inp of
                             []        -> []
                             [(g,out)] -> parse (fmap g px) out)

instance Monad Parser where
   -- (>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
   p >>= f = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                           []        -> []
                           [(v,out)] -> parse (f v) out)

-- Making choices

instance Alternative Parser where
   -- empty :: Parser a
   empty = P (\inp -> [])

   -- (<|>) :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
   p <|> q = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                           []        -> parse q inp
                           [(v,out)] -> [(v,out)])

-- Derived primitives

sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat p = do x <- item
           if p x then return x else empty

digit :: Parser Char
digit = sat isDigit

lower :: Parser Char
lower = sat isLower

upper :: Parser Char
upper = sat isUpper

letter :: Parser Char
letter = sat isAlpha

alphanum :: Parser Char
alphanum = sat isAlphaNum

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char x = sat (== x)

string :: String -> Parser String
string []     = return []
string (x:xs) = do char x
                   string xs
                   return (x:xs)

ident :: Parser String
ident = do x  <- lower
           xs <- many alphanum
           return (x:xs)

nat :: Parser Int
nat = do xs <- some digit
         return (read xs)

int :: Parser Int
int = do char '-'
         n <- nat
         return (-n)
       <|> nat

-- Handling spacing

space :: Parser ()
space = do many (sat isSpace)
           return ()

token :: Parser a -> Parser a
token p = do space
             v <- p
             space
             return v

identifier :: Parser String
identifier = token ident

natural :: Parser Int
natural = token nat

integer :: Parser Int
integer = token int

symbol :: String -> Parser String
symbol xs = token (string xs)
```

Comment: What is `Parsing`?

Comment: I added it to the original question.

Comment: You probably need something like `if ... then return ... else empty`. Here `empty` denotes "no result to return". Look at its definition in the library. Also look at the `sat` definition, which exhibits this "pattern". Also, you use of `parse` inside `noun` is _very_ suspicious: you should not have to use that and break the monad abstraction so early. You are expected to run something like `var <- oneOf nouns` instead.

Comment: unfortunately empty doesm't work. Could you suggest an alternative for not using `parse` inside `noun`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution thanks to chi:

```
noun :: Parser Tree
noun = do
  cs <- token identifier
  guard (elem cs nouns)
  let a = Leaf Noun cs
  return a
```